# Efficiently load videos that require authorization

Tags: html, video, oauth-2.0, stream, fetch

We are using an API that uses OAuth2 for authorization.

This API serves JSON, but also video content. We want to be able to display that video in a browser. It's not possible to simply set the video uri from the API in the HTML `<video>` tag, as this will not allow us to add the appropriate authorization headers.

I saw some solutions on stackoverflow for images that use the `data://` url to stringify the result of a `fetch()` or XHR call, but that seems like a bad idea for (potentially) multi-gigabyte videos.

Is there a way to set up a HTML5 `<video>` tag to stream videos that result from a `fetch()` call?

Comment: would it be possible to use the OAuth2 API to get a temporary URL (hashed to the user/IP/browser) and then use that as the `src` on the `video` tag (assuming you can validate the temp URL when serving the actual video)

Comment: No, we unfortunately don't have control over the server in this case.